# Can Not Unblock Application on High Sierra

Tags: security

The application can not be unblocked.

[image]

When I open the application it tells me that I must unblock the program in the mac os settings. I open the settings and it says 'Some software was blocked from loading.' Next to that is the unblock button which does not do anything.

I have tried:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security GKAutoRearm -bool NO

sudo spctl --master-disable
```

also I have tried launching the application from terminal via sudo:

```
 sudo ./Karabiner-Elements.app/Contents/MacOS/Karabiner-Elements
```

Nothing. It simply will not unblock.

Answer (score 2):

Magic Prefs is the issue. Get rid of that.

see:

https://www.uninstallmacapp.com/magicprefs-removal.html

and

https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1017